# ADF Data Flow flatten JSON to rows

Tags: json, azure-data-factory, azure-mapping-data-flow

IN ADF Data Flow how can I flatten JSON into rows rather than columns?

```
{                   
                "header": [
                    {                           
                        "main": {                                
                            "id": 1                               
                        },
                        "sub": [
                            {
                                "type": "a",                                   
                                "id": 2                                  
                            },
                            {
                                "type": "b",                                   
                                "id": 3                                 
                            }
                              
                              ]}]}
```

In ADF I'm using the flatten task and get the below result:

[image]

However the result I'm trying to achieve is merging the two id columns into one column like below:

[image]

Comment: Can you please include additional information such as another example for a complex JSON and its expected output. Please do provide information about any method/approach you have tried

Comment: @SaideepArikontham I have added more info. let me know if you can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since both `main_id` and `sub_id` belong in the same column, instead of using 1 flatten to flatten all the data, flatten both `main` and `sub` separately.

- I have taken the following JSON as source for my dataflow.

```
{
   "header":[
      {
         "main":{
            "id":1
         },
         "sub":[
            {
               "type":"a",
               "id":2
            },
            {
               "type":"b",
               "id":3
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "main":{
            "id":4
         },
         "sub":[
            {
               "type":"c",
               "id":5
            },
            {
               "type":"d",
               "id":6
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

- I have taken 2 flatten transformations `flattenMain` and `flattenSub` instead of 1 which use the same source.
- For `flattenMain`, I have unrolled by `header` and selected unroll root as `header`. Then created an additional column selecting source column `header.main.id`.

[image]

- The data preview for `flattenMain` would be:

[image]

- For `flattenSub`, I have unrolled by `header.sub` and selected unroll root as `header.sub`. Then created 2 additional column selecting source column `header.sub.id` as **id** column and `header.sub.type` as **type** column.

[image]

- The data preview for `flattenSub` transformation would be:

[image]

- Now I have applied `union` transformation on both `flattenMain` and `flattenSub`. I have applied `union by` using **Name**.

[image]

- The final data preview for this Union transformation will give the desired result.

[image]

**NOTE:** All the highlighted rows in output images indicate the result that would be achieved when we use the JSON sample provided in the question.